# How can I use the response from one function being called as an argument in calling another function?

Tags: javascript, fetch

```
uploadImage(extraFileItems[i])
          .then(response => 
            console.log(response)


            );
            
            // addItemToBin(bin, name, url);
```

I'm calling a function here that fetches data from an API. The API returns a promise with a result of what I want to pass as the "URL" parameter in the "addItemToBin" function. How can I call the "addItemToBin" function and pass it an argument of the promise result in the uploadImage function call?

I tried taking the response and setting it to a variable called url, however, that doesn't work. I also tried just calling the "addItemToBin" function in the .then however, that doesn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried just calling the "addItemToBin" function in the .then however, that doesn't work either.

That's the way to do it.

```
uploadImage(extraFileItems[i])
  .then(response => addItemToBin(bin, name, response));
```

If that didn't work for you then please provide more details.